# Updating non-unique key in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I want to insert into a `mysql` database. Before inserting it, I need to fill in NA values in a column containing a non-unique key. The filled in values need to be shared across groups, but cannot overlap with any preexisting values in the sql table.

Assuming that the maximum key value in the table is 5. I would need:

```
id    group    key
 1      A       1
 2      A       1
 3      B       NA
 4      B       NA
 5      C       2
 6      D       NA
```

To become:

```
id    group    key
 1      A       1
 2      A       1
 3      B       6
 4      B       6
 5      C       2
 6      D       7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way using `.rank` trick. It produces the same as your desired output.

```
max_key_value = 5

# boolean selector to select rows with NaN
null_sel = df["key"].isnull()
# replace the key by rank value
df.loc[null_sel, 'key'] = df.loc[null_sel, 'group'].rank(method='dense') + max_key_value
df

  group  id  key
0     A   1    1
1     A   2    1
2     B   3    6
3     B   4    6
4     C   5    2
5     D   6    7
```

Answer (score 0):

The best method I could find uses Categorical:

```
max_key_value = 5

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
           'group':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
           'key': [1, 1, np.NaN, np.NaN, 2, np.NaN]})

df['temp_key'] = pd.Categorical.from_array(df.group).codes + max_key_value + 1
df['key'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['key']), df['temp_key'], df['key'])
```